# Tag openrecord.js - is it the right tag name?

Tags: discussion

I've recently defined a new tag, [openrecord.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/openrecord.js). It's an [ORM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) for [Node.js](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js), and I wanted to be sure I named it the right way.

I had the possibility between [openrecord](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/openrecord) or [openrecord.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/openrecord.js). I noticed that [mongoose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mongoose) doesn't have the `.js`, but I felt that openrecord in general is a vague name.